# Django list in template without trailing comma in a nested for loop

Tags: django

I am trying to create a list of items in a Django template that are separated by commas, but with no comma after the last item. The list of items comes through a for loop within a for loop. I tried to do something like this.

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for o in thing.otherthing_set.all %}
            <span>{{ o.name }}: </span>
            {% if o.attribute == 'this' %}
                <span>{{ o.otherattribute}}</span>
                {% if not forloop.last %}
                    <span>, </span>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

But sometimes there is an extra comma because sometimes for the last item cycled through o.attribute == 'this' isn't always true.

What I would like to do is somehow have

```
{% for o in thing.otherthing_set.all %}
```

be filtered for just for o.attribute == 'this' before even going through the for loop, but it doesn't seem that this is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create method in the model which returns objects from `otherthing_set` with `o.attribute == 'this'` and iterate over them in the template

Comment: .. which you would do with a query filter: `return self.otherthing_set.filter(attribute='this')`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!